# Subir imagen con Ajax, Jquery, Asp.net WebForms, En N Capas no MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

espero puedan ayudarme llevo dias tratando de subir un archivo ya sea en a la raiz de mi proyecto o en X rutra en asp.net no MVC encontre un link en youtube de como hacerlo en MVC por medio de un controlador pero al momento de trabajar el ajax para el parametro "data" se necesita la vista razor la cual no tengo en asp.net, no obstante cree una carpeta y agregue un controlador MVC la cual me creo carpetas adicionales tas como view, models etc, quise implementarlo de esa forma pero sin mayor exito, les dejo el codigo:

[image: Codigo del Controlador]

[image: Codigo del Ajax]

Espero me ayuden llevo 3 dias sin poder realizarlo

Comment: Juan hola, te recomiendo que agregues el código por el cual estas preguntado , las imágenes ayudan pero a veces las preguntas con solo imágenes no son bien recibidas por la comunidad, te recomiendo que leas primero (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Puede ser algo tonto pero en la linea de codigo donde haces  el append al FormData(). En lugar de pasarle "FileFoto" cambialo por "fileUpload" por que así se llama el parametro en tu Controller. Y otra cosa como dice @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO si pudieras colocar el codigo en texto sería mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Buenas tardes amigos pues en realidad estoy dispuesto a que me ofrezcan propuestas de como subir imagenes con ajax y jquery a una carpeta en X ruta, que no sea en MVC porque no domino esa arquitectura sino WebForms, con Input File e Input button,  de todas formas subire lo poco que avance en ese punto por favor ayuda